# Sql Server Inserts timing out

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to insert multiple rows into a simple table in Sql Server 2008. The table doesn't have any indexes other than the Primary Key.

I'm doing the inserts as follows

```
insert into TestTable 
(Col1,Col2, Col3,Col4, Col5)
select 1,1,1,1,GETDATE()
union all
select 1,2,3,1,GETDATE()
union all
select 1,5,2,1,GETDATE()
union all
select 1,4,15,1,GETDATE()
```

If I do this for a large number of rows ( say 400 ) and run the operation multiple times,
the insert operation begins to take a huge amount of time.

Is there any way to further optimize the inserts?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Running 400 UNION's is definitely going to make it slower -- although I am not sure what "huge" amount of time means.  This is not the right way to insert 400 records into a table.

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into TestTable (Col1,Col2, Col3,Col4, Col5)
VALUES (1,1,1,1,GETDATE()), (1,1,1,1,GETDATE()), (1,1,1,1,GETDATE()), ...
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you commit rather frequently.
this should reduce rollback segment usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to chunk the data.  Load the first 100 records, commit, then repeat.  400 records is not a lot.  You can typically insert thousands of records at one time.  All inserts are written to the log for rollback purposes.  The log file is cleared when you commit.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably compile time, not execution time.

If you have 400 rows exactly the same then generate 400 rows *first*

```
insert into TestTable 
   (Col1,Col2, Col3,Col4, Col5)
select
   1,1,1,1,GETDATE()
FROM
   (SELECT TOP 400 * FROM master.dbo.spt_values ORDER BY 1) foo
```

Comment: Sorry, I realized that my question wasn't very accurate - I'm not actually trying to insert identical rows.